# ansible if else construct

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Heres my if else Ansible logic ..

```
- name: Check certs exist
  stat: path=/etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ rootDomain }}/fullchain.pem
  register: st

- include: ./_common/check-certs-renewable.yaml
  when: st.stat.exists

- include: ./_common/create-certs.yaml
  when: not st.stat.exists
```

This code boils down to:

> IF certs exist
>
> renew certs
>
> ELSE
>
> create certs
>
> END IF

Is this the correct approach or is there a better approach to the IF ELSE construct in ansible?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What you have there should work and is one way of doing it.

Alternatively, you could use a Jinja query to reduce it to 2 tasks, such that:

```
 - name: Check certs exist
   stat: path=/etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ rootDomain }}/fullchain.pem
   register: st

- include: "{{ './_common/check-certs-renewable.yaml' if st.stat.exists else './_common/create-certs.yaml' }}"
```

However, it's more a matter of personal preference than anything else, and your way is more readable, so I would just stick with that IMHO.

Comment: how about if the value was a variable? let's say: else './_common/{{ file }}'

Comment: w00t, if the answer doesn't fit that case, maybe open another question for it.

Comment: I would think it fits the case since this page is in the top results when googling ansible if else.

Comment: It looks more like a jinja2 question that an if/else question

Answer (score 10):

What about the following:

```yaml
condition_arg: >-
  {%- if ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' -%}
  'param for ubuntu'
  {%- elif ansible_distribution == 'Debian' -%}
  'params for debian'
  {%- else -%}
  'what else'
  {%- end -%}
```

Kind of `if-else` statement.. ? They have been used in some projects with Ansible.
This form isn't available from the official docs but from an active thread on [stackexchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/907164/ansible-conditionally-define-variables-in-vars-file-if-a-certain-condition-is-m).

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer. Can you rewrite this to make it less ambiguous? Thanks!

Comment: in my case, I need `{%- endif -%}` instead of `{%- end -%}`

Answer (score 4):

The following can be used if you want to search if a register is empty. The msg Unavailable is printed if php -version info is not found.If it is found, it prints the output of the command.

[image]

```
- name: Check php
  shell: php -version
  register: result

- name: Print register
  debug:
    msg: '{{ (result.stdout) | ternary( (result.stdout),"Unavailable") }}'
```

Comment: Please, do not insert code as a picture